# How get mean of weighted matrixes without loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

I have groups of scalars and matrixes respertively:

```
w1, w2...wn
A1, A2... An
```

How get

```
w1*A1 + w2*A2 + ... + wn*An
```

without loop?
And how efficiently get

```
w1*(b1*c1) + w2*(b2*c2) + ... + wn*(bn*cn)
```

Where `bi` and `ci` are vectors but `bi*ci` is matrix, not a scalar?

Comment: Have you tried to just type what you wrote (like `w1*A1 + w2*A2 + ... + wn*An`) into Matlab? It's basic Matlab matrix operations: [times](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) and [plus](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html).

Comment: maeby i should create vector `w` from `wi` and matrix `A` from rehaped `Ai` and after this use `bsxfun` but is there another way without reshaping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**: I have a better solution.

If your matrices An are stored in a 3-D matrix of size `P x Q x N` such that `An = A(:,:,n)` for `n = 1, 2, ..., N` and your weights are stored in a weight vector `w` of size `1 x N` then the following command does the weighted average:

```
B = reshape(w*reshape(permute(A,[3,1,2]),N,[]),[P,Q]);
```

Comment: my weight stored in vector. And the question about matrix strorage still opened. Can remember only cell (not for this task) and about converting each matrix to vector and putting this vectors in another matrix.

Comment: I have edited my reply. Have a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Maeby it is better for me, but it seems better to use index manipulations instead of reshape when GPU is using. Thanks for you decision, it works good enough in my task.

Answer (score 0):

First problem can be solved by `bsxfun` as follows:

```
% create matrices
a=[1 2]
b=randi(9,[3 3 2])

% now you will have to reshape a, so that its non-singleton dimensions match b
% i.e. a is 1 x 2 and b is 3 x 3 x 2, so second dimension of (=2) should match 
% 3rd dimension of b (=2). Thus a should be of shape `1 x 1 x 2`. Then you can 
% multiply using bsxfun and sum along 3rd dimension as follows

sum(bsxfun(@times, permute(a,[3 1 2]), b),3)
```